# Flutter Firestore Query with whereIn: List is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When querying with where() in Firestore, it succeeds when I give the values one by one, but when I export a list, nothing returns.

Successful sample code:

```
List temp = example.sharedPreferences.getStringList(example.userList);
Firestore.instance.collection('example').where('id', whereIn: ['77','30','71','13']).snapshots(),
```

Failed sample code:

```
List temp = example.sharedPreferences.getStringList(example.userList);
Firestore.instance.collection('example').where('id', whereIn: [temp]).snapshots(),
```

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp` is already a list therefore in the failed sample code, you don't need to use `[]`, just do the following:

```
List temp = example.sharedPreferences.getStringList(example.userList);
Firestore.instance.collection('example').where('id', whereIn: temp).snapshots()
```

Comment: It escaped my attention, it worked.
Thanks.